# Add to JSON without overwriting (with Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

First of all, my apologies if this question has been asked before. I've been searching for hours but could not find a conclusive answer.

I'm currently working on a Google Chrome extension, whenever a **new** Chrome user (who is logged in) uses it, I want that user's email address logged in a JSON file that is (for now - testing purposes, no real accounts will be used) hosted at http://myjson.com.

In order to retrieve the user's Google Account, I'm using chrome.identity. That works very well. My problem is that I can't seem to find any way to:

- Search the online JSON if the user already exists, **without** retrieving the whole thing as a JSON string/object
- Add a new user to the JSON without, again, retrieving the entire object, adding to it locally, and then overwriting the existing one.

This is my code right now. What it does, is simply retrieve all of the JSON, change the things I want locally, and then basically overwrite it. Which is not what I want.

```
function readApi(){
    if($.isEmptyObject(userObj)) {
        chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo) {
            userObj = {id: userInfo.id, email: userInfo.email};
        });
    }

    async function loadJson(url) { // (1)
        let response = await fetch(url); // (2)

        if (response.status === 200) {
            return await response.json(); // (3)
        }

        throw new Error(response.status.toString());
    }

    loadJson('the_url_from_myjson')
        .then((value) => {
            const userInJSON = value.users.find( user => user.id === userObj.id);

            console.log(value);

            if(!userInJSON) {
                let users = value.users;
                users.push(userObj);
                value.users = users;

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'the_url_from_myjson',
                    type: "PUT",
                    data: JSON.stringify(value),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        let json = JSON.stringify(data);
                    }
                })
            }

        })
        .catch(alert); // Error: 404 (4)

    setTimeout(readApi, 5000);
}readApi();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it necessary to be saved in the JSON object? Otherwise it sounds like you could benefit from using a database, which will solve just what you ask for. If you don't care about the consistency of your objects, a document database like MongoDb should probably suffice in this case :)

Comment: Yes this sounds like a database would be the best option for you.

Comment: Both things you are asking for are really only possible if you provided/created an _API_ for such purposes, on the server where you want to store the JSON data.

Comment: @RKrogh yeah, I would have definitely used a database if I had that option right now. Alas, I do not, sadly.

Comment: @misorude Ah, right. Would you happen to have any pointers I can look at to get started with that?